# Chatterbot - No module named 'chatterbot.trainers' - python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I am using `python 3.x`. I am getting an error while running this code:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer # method to train the chatbot
from chatterbot import ChatBot # import the chatbot

bot = ChatBot('Test')

conv = open('chats.txt', 'r').readlines()

bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer) # set the trainer

bot.train(conv) # train the bot

while True:
request = input('You: ')
response = bot.get_response(request)

print('Bot: ', response)
```

**Error:**

```
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot.trainers'; 'chatterbot' is 
not a package
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Is your file named `chatterbot.py`?

Comment: Yes you are right